# WP Hide parent container when both child fields (acf fields) are empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Could do with some help as I've tried a few things but no luck...

I have a container div that has two fields inside it (wordpress acf). I can show the fields if they have content and they don't dhow if the are empty. What I need now is to show the container div if one or both fields have content or hide the container field if both fields are empty.

Current code

```
<div class="header-contact">    
<?php if( get_field('header_tel', 'option') ): ?>

                        <p>Tel No: <a href="tel:<?php the_field('header_tel', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('header_tel', 'option'); ?></a></p>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if( get_field('header_email', 'option') ): ?>
                    <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('header_email', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('header_email', 'option'); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be great...

Comment: And what is the actual problem - you’re not aware what logical operators there are, or what? (Btw, since you are calling these functions multiple times, you should store the result in variables.)

Comment: Basically, wasn't sure how to go about it. Thanks for the tip on the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
<?php if( get_field('header_tel', 'option') || get_field('header_email', 'option') ): ?>
   <div class="header-contact"> 
     <?php if( get_field('header_tel', 'option') ): ?>
       <p>Tel No: <a href="tel:<?php the_field('header_tel', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('header_tel', 'option'); ?></a></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if( get_field('header_email', 'option') ): ?>
       <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('header_email', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('header_email', 'option'); ?></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```